# jQuery function clear/stop

Tags: jquery

I have the following piece of code - [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/vincepettit/hdeW5/)

The problem i'm having at the moment is layering up of the functions if you mouseover/off. I thought adding a stop function would help this out but if you run the mouse over the trigger a few times it breaks and the function stops working.

Would be great if someone could help me out on this!

Comment: Works great in Chrome here...which browser are you having issues in?

Comment: Looks good in Opera & Chrome & FF (cant test IE right now - using nix OS) have you tried setting `.stop(true,true)`?

Comment: Sorry, wrong link! Updated the link now.

Comment: looks like it gets stuck during animation and then ether show nor hide is triggered ... should work  with `.stop(true,true)` but the animation will be less smooth

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use `stop(true, true)`. See the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) `.stop( [ clearQueue ], [ jumpToEnd ] )` [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XVHZJ/)

```
jQuery("#offer-logo").hover(function() {
    jQuery("#offer-content").stop(true, true).show(250);
}, function() {
    jQuery("#offer-content").stop(true, true).hide(300);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of stop try using `.delay(100)` Seems to fix it, at least on FF4.